# Django Beginner Forms, not able to get loop forms

Tags: python, django, forms, django-templates, django-contenttypes

I have a model name Fightmma and a model named Fightmmacard. Commentform works for Fightcard but not for Fightmma.

Each fightcard is made of fights. When I comment on any fight, the last fight on the card gets the comment.

My Commentform looks for the content type and the id. I am not able to pass the correct fight id to the Commentform properly. In my views it loop though the fights but the id is stored for the last fight only.

My python isn't that great but I've been trying for 12 hours

All help appreciated.

Using Django1.11

models.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from datetime import date
from django.contrib.auth.models import User #Blog author or commenter
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericForeignKey
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericRelation


class CommentManager(models.Manager):
    def filter_by_instance(self, instance):
        content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(instance.__class__)
        obj_id = instance.id
        qs = super(CommentManager, self).filter(content_type=content_type, object_id= obj_id)
        return qs



class Comment(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
    body = models.TextField(blank=True)
    post_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey()

    objects = CommentManager()


    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-post_date"]

    def __str__(self):
        """
        String for representing the Model object.
        """
        len_title=75
        if len(self.body)>len_title:
            titlestring=self.body[:len_title] + '...'
        else:
            titlestring=self.body
        return titlestring     





#mmmmmmmmmmm
class Fightmma(models.Model):
    Custom_Number = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    Wiki_Event_Number_Fight = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    Event_Number_2 = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    Left_Names_Natural_Spaces = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    Right_Names_Natural_Spaces = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    Custom_Number_Decimal = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=3, null=True, blank=True)
    Event_Number = models.ForeignKey('Fightcardmma', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank= True, null= True)
    comments = GenericRelation('Comment')

    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return str(self.Custom_Number_Decimal)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('Custom_Number_Decimal',)

    @property
    def comments(self):
        instance = self
        qs = Comment.objects.filter_by_instance(instance)
        return qs

    @property
    def get_content_type(self):
        instance = self
        content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(instance.__class__)
        return content_type






class Fightcardmma(models.Model):
    Event_Number = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    Event_Wiki_Name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    Event_Wiki_Link = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    Event_Date = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    Event_Stadium = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    Event_Location = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    Event_Attendance = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    Event_Date_2 = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    comments = GenericRelation('Comment')

    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return str(self.Event_Number)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('Event_Number',)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("aland:detail", kwargs={"id": self.id})

    @property
    def comments(self):
        instance = self
        qs = Comment.objects.filter_by_instance(instance)
        return qs

    @property
    def get_content_type(self):
        instance = self
        content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(instance.__class__)
        return content_type
```

views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.template.defaulttags import register
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.views import generic
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType


from .forms import FightcardmmaForm, CommentForm
from .models import Fighter, Fight, Fightcard, Result, Fightermma, Fightmma, Fightcardmma, Resultmma, FightcardmmaComment, FightmmaComment, Comment



def fightcardmma_detail(request, id=None): #retrieve
    instance = get_object_or_404(Fightcardmma, id=id)
    fightqueryset = Fight.objects.all()
    fighterqueryset = Fighter.objects.all()
    fightcardqueryset = Fightcard.objects.all()
    resultqueryset = Result.objects.all()
    fightmmaqueryset = Fightmma.objects.all()
    fightermmaqueryset = Fightermma.objects.all()
    fightcardmmaqueryset = Fightcardmma.objects.all()
    resultmmaqueryset = Resultmma.objects.all()



    bu = Fightcardmma.objects.filter(Event_Number=instance.Event_Number) 
    bu2 = Fightcardmma.objects.all().count()


    for a in bu:  #for each fight a in event bu 
        iu =a.fightmma_set.all() #curiousty all the fights in event a
        fighterfights = {} 
        fighterdetails = {}
        for c in iu:   # for each fight c in event iu


            initial_data = {
                "content_type": c.get_content_type,
                "object_id": c.id
            } 

############## looping though fights ########              
            form = CommentForm()
            form = CommentForm(request.POST or None, initial=initial_data,)
            if form.is_valid():
                c_type = form.cleaned_data.get("content_type")
                content_type = ContentType.objects.get(model=c_type)
                obj_id = form.cleaned_data.get('object_id')
                content_data = form.cleaned_data.get("body")
                new_comment, created = Comment.objects.get_or_create(
                                    author = request.user,
                                    content_type= content_type,
                                    object_id = obj_id,
                                    body = content_data,
                                )
                refresh1 = "/aland/fightcardmma/"+str(instance.id)
                return HttpResponseRedirect(refresh1)          



##### end of loop below if comment for fightcard ##################                

    initial_data2 = {
            "content_type": instance.get_content_type,
            "object_id": instance.id
    }

    formunique = CommentForm()
    formunique = CommentForm(request.POST or None, initial=initial_data2)
    if formunique.is_valid():
        c_type = formunique.cleaned_data.get("content_type")
        content_type = ContentType.objects.get(model=c_type)
        obj_id = formunique.cleaned_data.get('object_id')
        content_data = formunique.cleaned_data.get("body")
        new_comment, created = Comment.objects.get_or_create(
                            author = request.user,
                            content_type= content_type,
                            object_id = obj_id,
                            body = content_data
                        )
        refresh1= "/aland/fightcardmma/"+str(instance.id)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(refresh1)

    comments = instance.comments


    context = {
            "fight_list": fightqueryset,
            "fighter_list": fighterqueryset,
            "fightcard_list": fightcardqueryset,
            "result_list": resultqueryset,
            "fightmma_list": fightmmaqueryset,
            "fightermma_list": fightermmaqueryset,
            "fightcardmma_list": fightcardmmaqueryset,
            "resultmma_list": resultmmaqueryset,
            "title": "List" ,                
            "bu": bu ,
            "iu": iu ,
            "instance": instance,
            "fighterfights": fighterfights,
            "fighterdetails" : fighterdetails,
            "comments": comments,        
            "formunique": formunique,
            "form": form,

    }
    return render(request, "fightcardmma_detail.html", context)


######
```

forms.py snippet

```
from django import forms

from .models import Fightcardmma, Fightmma, Comment


class CommentForm(forms.Form):
    content_type = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput)
    object_id = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.HiddenInput)
    body = forms.CharField(label='', widget=forms.Textarea)
```

fightcardmma_detail.html snippet

```
<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% load get %}

              {{ a.Custom_Number_Decimal}}
              <form method="POST" action="."> {% csrf_token %}
                  {{ form}}
                  <input type='submit' value='Post fight comment' class='btn btn-default'>
```

urls.py snippet

```
from django.conf.urls import  url
from django.contrib import admin
from . import views
from .views import (
    fightcardmma_detail,
    )
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^fightcardmma/(?P<id>\d+)/$', fightcardmma_detail, name='detail'),
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Added this to the views.py

```
fightform = []
for fight in fightcard
    initial_data = {
        "content_type": fight.get_content_type,
        "object_id": fight.id
    } 


    Form[fight] = CommentForm(request.POST or None, initial=initial_data,)
        if form.is_valid(): ### same as before

fightform.append(Form[fight])
fightset = instance.fightmma_set.all()
fightset_and_fightform = zip(fightset, fightform)

context{
"fightset_and_fightform":fightset_and_fightform, ### added to context
}
```

Then following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48402667/django-template-tags-beginner) I could pass it through the templates.