# Django template tags beginner

Tags: django, django-templates

How can I do this

Example.html

```
{% for number in numbers %}

    {{ number }}  ##### 1
    {{ Form1 }}   ##### first loop

    {{ number }} ##### 2
    {{ Form2 }}  ##### second loop

{% endfor %}
```

Form1, Form2... have been passed though views

Answer (score 0):

The easiest place to fix this might be in your view. Zip the numbers and forms together:

```
numbers = [1,2]
forms = [Form1, Form2]

numbers_and_forms = zip(numbers, forms)
```

Then in your template you loop through them together.

```
{% for number, form in numbers_and_forms %}
  {{ number }}
  {{ form }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: It's a good answer, running into this problem now. "zip argument #1 must support iteration"

Comment: The code above wouldn't give that error, so you need to show what you are doing differently.

Comment: I had forgot brackets, Thank you so much. I hadn't made progress in days. Solved.